# Extracting decimal value from a number in imacros

Tags: javascript, regex, imacros

I'm extracting data from [this](http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=20-Lacs) website

And using this code to get the number with decimal from the text, but it gives only the whole number not along with the decimal

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=span ATTR=CLASS:proPriceField&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET ProPrice EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/[0-9,]+/);")
```

This gives `14` instead of `14.1`

Any suggestion what changes should be made to the code, so as o get the proper output.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You want decimals only? Well, by the way, you used a comma to separate the numbers in the regex, and a dot in your test...

Comment: Not ONLY decimal, but along with decimal....Right now the output I get is suppose "14.2 Lacs", I get 14, but I want to extract 14.2

Answer (score 0):

The regex you're looking for is

```
\d+(?:(?:\.|,)\d+|)
```

Take a look at this [online test](https://regex101.com/r/UxuMqt/1) on Regex101

Instead of using `[0-9]`, you can simply use `\d` to simplify your regex:

- `\d+` Matches one or more occurrences of digits
- `(?:` Start of a non-capturing group (2x)
- `\.` As the dot is a selector in regex, it must be escaped.
- `|` The OR operator (to match or the literal dot, or a comma)
- `,` Literal text (comma)
- `)` End of the capturing group
- `\d+` Matches one or more occurrences of digits (the decimal part)
- `|` The OR operator (to match or the decimal part, or the digit by itself (nothing))
- `)` End of the capturing group